# append head doesn't work in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

My `layout.jade` is following:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-grid.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-reboot.css')
        script(src="/javascripts/core.js")
        script(src="/javascripts/jquery.js")
        script(src="/javascripts/jquery-slim.js")
        script(src="/javascripts/bootstrap.js")
    body
        block content
```

My `place.jade` is following:

```
extends layout

append head
    script(src="/javascripts/custom.js")
    ...
```

When I serve templete, I see

[image]

Which meand appending doesn't render at all.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append works only with block so the correct code of layout.jade is

```
doctype html
html
    head
    block scripts
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-grid.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-reboot.css')
        script(src="/javascripts/core.js")
        script(src="/javascripts/jquery.js")
        script(src="/javascripts/jquery-slim.js")
        script(src="/javascripts/bootstrap.js")
    body
        block content
```

and for place.jade will be

```
extends layout

append scripts
    script(src="/javascripts/custom.js")
    ...
```